# Why is this code undefined behaviour?

Tags: go, undefined-behavior

```
package main

import "time"
import "fmt"

var i int = 0

func loopInc() {
    for {
        i++
    }
}

func main() {
    go loopInc()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

This code would always print 0.

I dumped the executable file and found that the go my `loopInc` function was compiled to a do-nothing loop. `i++` doesn't exist in it.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

It's all explained in the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

In this example, there is not a happens before relationship between incrementing `i` and and printing `i`. Because there is not a happens before relationship, the main goroutine may or may not see the changes to `i`.

The compiler is allowed to optimize away `i++` because there's no guarantee that the changes to `i` will be observed.